# Empty Base Class Optimization (EBCO) and Java

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-optimization

The *EBCO* is a pretty known idiom in C++, here a few links:

- *EBCO* on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)
- *EBCO* on [WikiBooks](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization)
- *EBCO* on [the web](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html)

A citation from one of the above mentioned links:

> Allows the size of an empty base subobject to be zero.

The reason and intent of this idiom is quite clear and so is the way it works (or at least, I did my best to understand it in my past).

Anyway, just for the sake of curiosity, I was guessing if there exists something similar to the *EBCO* in Java.
I mean, do I have any benefit in treating base empty classes *differently* (if yes, I'd like to know what *differently* means in this case), or it simply doesn't matter what I do with them?

As an example, it is possible to define classes that offer only static data members and static member methods, so theoretically there would be room for such an optimization.
Anyway, I have absolutely no idea if it makes sense to natter about that when one is dealing with a language like Java...

Comment: EBCO is an optimization applied by the compiler. What benefit do you perceive it has for the code, other than saving one byte? Why would you care about this?

Comment: As I said, *just for the sake of curiosity*. I'm curious to know if it makes sense to speak about something like EBCO with languages like Java. That's all. Just curious. :-)